# devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAllAsync<HtmlTextAreaElement> is returning the value in debug mode only

Tags: c#, dom, async-await, webview2

Sample code:

```cs
var devToolsContext = await webView.CoreWebView2.CreateDevToolsContextAsync();

HtmlTextAreaElement[] txtAreaElements = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAllAsync<HtmlTextAreaElement>("textarea");
```

I am trying to fetch `HtmlTextAreaElements` from a web page.
Here the issue is that if I have a breakpoint at this line, I am able to see the list of `HtmlTextAreaElements`. Otherwise, no elements returned.

Could you please let me know any possible solutions and share your experiences if you ever have experienced such type of issues?

Thanks in advance.

I've already tried several ways like to wait until the status of the task is changed to RanToCompletion

```cs
while (taTask.Status != System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
{
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `HtmlTextAreaElement[] txtAreaElements = await devToolsContext.QuerySelectorAllAsync<HtmlTextAreaElement>("textarea");`. That method returns a `HtmlElement[]` otherwise -- Add more context. Where / when are you calling this code? I assume **after** the navigation has completed, right? Also include the WebView2 initialization procedure, it's part of that context, as is the .NET version you're targeting and versions of the main packages (`WebView2` and `WebView2.DevTools.Dom`)